# python3 kivy builder: -> [CRITICAL] [Application ] No window is created. Terminating application run

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

The attempt was to build a kivy application with Python3.6 however error recieved "window not building"

The kivy file
[image: The kivy file]

Directory saved
[image: Directory saved]

Displayed error
[image: Displayed error]

Written code
[image: Wwritten code]

Comment: Have you tried to run it from `cmd prompt`?

Comment: yes but still isn't working....same message received

Comment: You dont want brackets around `Widget` in your kv file, since that will be your root widget. Not sure that will fix the error tho

Comment: Please avoid posting images of text.

Answer (score 3):

Like @el3ien mentioned in the comment, in the .kv file, "Widgets" element should not have brackets around it. The element with no angled brackets is the root element and root element is returned by builder function. No window is created as no root is returned by the build/builder function

There can be one and only one root element. Unless you denote root element by

```
return RootClassName()
```

in build function from the python file, Python won't know which is root from the .kv file if all elements have angled brackets around it.

Answer (score 3):

Anyone having this problem
imported Window . paste it in top of your code (.py)

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
```

It should fix it. It  worked for me..